# Input mismatch when reading from a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I have a file with data organized like so:

`Hyundai Santa Fe`

`2005  16999   8`

`Mercury Mountaineer AWD`

`2004 17999 7.5`

`Mercury Grand Marquis`

`2006 19999 12.5`

The first line being car name, next line being year, price, and discount amount.  I'm trying to read a file with many of these lines and the kicker is that price and discount isn't always represented as a double.

Here is a snippet of code which I wrote but does not properly parse through the lines.  I get an input mismatch exception.

What am I doing wrong?

```
try {

         Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(file);
         while(scanFile.hasNext()) {   

            String carName = scanFile.nextLine();

            int year = scanFile.nextInt();
            double listPrice = scanFile.nextDouble();
            double percentDiscount = scanFile.nextDouble();

            double discountAmount = calculateDiscount(listPrice, percentDiscount);
            double netPrice = calculateNetPrice(listPrice, discountAmount);

            carList.add(new Proj1CarData(carName, year, listPrice, percentDiscount, discountAmount, netPrice));

         }
      } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println("Unable to locate the file supplied.");
      }
```

Comment: If you read a file, aren't those strings by default? If so, you would need to parse them first.

Comment: @Xbit that is sort of what [`Scanner.nextDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) does... Would be a pretty useless method otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextLine()` is defined as

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.  Since this method continues to search
>   through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of
>   the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are
>   present.

meaning that `nextLine()` will read from the current position to line separator.

After a first call to `double percentDiscount = scanFile.nextDouble();`, the Scanner's cursor is at after 8 in line `2005  16999   8`.

On the second iteration of the loop, `String carName = scanFile.nextLine();` will read an empty string as there is no string between 8 and the line separator. Then, `int year = scanFile.nextInt();` throws an `InputMismatchException` as the cursor now is looking at the `Mercury Mountaineer AWD`.

I don't know if I was able to explain myself well.

To resolve this problem, simplified version would be just to add extra `nextLine()` call at the end of the loop:

```
String carName = scanFile.nextLine();

int year = scanFile.nextInt();
double listPrice = scanFile.nextDouble();
double percentDiscount = scanFile.nextDouble();
scanFile.nextLine();
```

I suppose the better way of handling this is to read each line using `nextLine()` and check if the line is carname or year/price/discount info or not.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

After consuming your `int` and your two `double`s, you need to **consume the `line feed`** before reading the next car name.

Thus, simply adding `scanFile.nextLine()` right after your `carList.add(...)` should do the trick.

Actually, just to handle the case of the final line, *assuming that there is no line feed* after the last `double` data in your input file, you should use:

```
if(scanLine.hasNextLine()) {
    scanLine.nextLine();
}
```

in order to protect the call to `scanLine.nextLine()` that would throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

Cheers!